# What are the under-the-hood mechanics for locking an ERC-20 token?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, openzeppelin-contracts

I have some idea of what "locking ether" means, but I need to understand for sure.  AFAIK, tokens exist at some address, but according to many sources, the token is locked in a smart contract for some period of time.  What is the reality?  Do tokens get locked at the source address for the time-limit, or at some temporary neutral storage location (address) before it is sent to the destination?  I am wondering in the case where someone wants to prevent themselves from using some amount of tokens using this locking mechanism.  In that case, there is no destination.  How does the code work?  The source and destination are the same, or do the funds get locked in a neutral storage location to be returned to the initial address after the vesting period is over.

Comment: This [question] (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/73427/how-to-lock-eth-into-a-smart-contract-for-a-certain-amount-of-time/73440) helps somewhat, but it refers to a third-party API.  Why doesn't the ERC-20 interface handle locking tokens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but I'll address some of the points you made.

> AFAIK, tokens exist at some address, but according to many sources, the token is locked in a smart contract for some period of time.

Just to be clear: ERC-20 tokens only ever exist in the token contract as a balance associated with an address. They never exist anywhere else. When a transfer occurs between two addresses, all that is happening is that two balance variables in the token contract are changed.

> Do tokens get locked at the source address for the time-limit, or at some temporary neutral storage location (address) before it is sent to the destination?

I think you're asking about something like Open Zeppelin's [TokenTimeLock](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc20#TokenTimelock) utility. This isn't part of the standard specification, but is a separate contract that interfaces with an ERC-20 contract to allow time locks to be used.

> The source and destination are the same, or do the funds get locked in a neutral storage location to be returned to the initial address after the vesting period is over.

As per my first point, ERC-20 tokens never leave the token contract - they only exist as a balance inside the contract itself. All the time lock does is prevent these balances from being changed (for a particular address or set of addresses) for the desired length of time.

---

**Edit:**

Just looking at the [TokenTimeLock](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/TokenTimelock.sol) code, it works by checking whether the unlock block number has been reached:

```
require(releaseTime_ > block.timestamp, "TokenTimelock: release time is before current time");
```

I'm sure other locking mechanism exist elsewhere, but this seems the most pertinent given you've used the [openzeppelin-contracts](/questions/tagged/openzeppelin-contracts) tag.

Comment: Great answer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: does the contract code poll the chain for the latest block's timestamp?

Comment: Also, it doesn't make sense exactly what you say, " two balance variables in the token contract are changed"...how does this really happen?  contracts are just code right?

Comment: For your first question: When a user wants to transfer an amount of tokens, they submit a transaction. When that transaction is mined and put into a block to be included in the blockchain, certain details of that block become available to, and can be used by, the transaction. The block number is one of the values that is available.

Comment: Second question: There's actually only one variable that gets changed - the `_balances` mapping. Inside the mapping each address is mapped to its balance. The source address has its balanced reduced by the amount that is added to the destination address.

Comment: See the `_balances` variable and `_transfer()` function, here -> https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol

Comment: I suppose my next question is how do wallets keep track of various contracts on various blocks? An external DB, or how?

Comment: Good question. It might depend on the implementation, and the number of addresses that the wallet it listing balances for. If it's lots of different addresses, then it may require a back-end database, or some other way to organise the required data. If it's just one or a few addresses, then the wallet itself can register for and listen to relevant blockchain events.

Comment: Im a little paranoid...whats being done on-chain vs off-chain

Comment: Wallet apps exist in the off-chain world, but can register for notifications for events that happen on-chain (e.g. a balance being updated in the blockchain data).